# Cannot access WCF service hosted in Apache with mod-mono

Tags: wcf, apache, mono, mod-mono

I have a WCF service using basicHttpBinding hosted in Apache 2.2.15, using mod_mono in CentOS. I added the following directives to the end of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to enable WCF services:

```
MonoServerPath default /usr/bin/mod-mono-server4
AddType application/x-asp-net .svc
```

When I try to call an operation in the service from a client in windows:

```
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();

    IService1 service1 = ChannelFactory<IService1>.CreateChannel(binding, new EndpointAddress(new Uri(`"http://ipaddress/svctest/Service1.svc"`)));

    string test= service1.GetData(1);
```

The following Exception is thrown:

> ProtocolException was unhandled:
>   The content type application/x-asp-net of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 109 bytes of the response were: '<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="svcfiletest.Service1" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs"% >

When I access the service through the browser it downloads the file instead of showing the service description.

> When I use `svcutil`http://ipaddress/svcutil/Service1.svc?wsdl I get
>   the following message:
>
> The document at the url `http://ipaddress/svctest/Service1.svc` was
>   not recognized as a known document type. The error message from each
>   known type may help you fix the problem:
>   -Report from 'XML Schema' is 'Name cannot begin with the '%' character, hecadecimal value 0x25. Line 1, position 2.'.
>   -Report from 'WSDL Document' is 'There is an error in XML document (1,2).'.
>   -Name cannot begin with the '%' character, hexadecimal value 0x25. Line 1,position 2.

It seems that its getting the text from Service1.svc:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="svcfiletest.Service1" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs" %>
```

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you also actually load the module somewhere in your `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` ?

You need both the `Include /etc/apache2/mod_mono.conf` (or put it into a config directory that's included by your `http.conf`) and the `LoadModule mono_module /usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_mono.so`

See http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono.

**My setup - manually starting mod-mono**

I manually compiled mod-mono, this is my mod_mono.conf: http://pastebin.com/qp8vxHQ7.  You need to manually start mod-mono-server with this setup.

I checked out [this module](https://github.com/baulig/Provcon-Faust/tree/master/TestWCF) in `~/Sites/`, apache picks that up as `http://localhost/~Martin/`.

Then, I started mod-mono-server4 in the `~/Sites` directory like this:

```
    mod-mono-server4 --port 9000 --applications /~martin/Service:Service --verbose
```

This is working fine.

**My setup - automatically starting mod-mono**

Also tested an alternative setup: http://pastebin.com/tYWk3tC9.  This lets apache start mod-mono.

Comment: I have "Include conf.d/*.conf" and inside /etc/httpd/conf.d I have mod-mono.conf. 
Inside mono.conf I have " <IfModule !mod_mono.c> LoadModule mono_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_mono.so </IfModule> ". 
I was able to open the test project that comes with mod_mono in my windows browser with mod-mono-server2. But for a WCF service with mod-mono-server4 its not working.

Comment: Hmm, I just tried and I had to add that `AddType application/x-asp-net .svc` to `mod-mono.conf`.